# generated column to add timestamp column with counter in mysql mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i'm trying to use generated columns to add a timestamp column with an int column that holds a counter in milliseconds 
it looks something like this:

```
datetime_created timestamp current timestamp
counter int 20
//for example i have 2019 31 10 10 00 00 as timestamp and 
//9567.4356 as counter
```

how can i add the timestamp with the counter in milliseconds
 to get generated column like datetime_ended?

Comment: Why do you need this? A timestamp is stored numerically, there's practically no overhead to converting it to a numeric timestamp

Comment: Why is the counter so low? A timestamp in milliseconds should be 12 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generated column like this example:

```
create table mytest (
  date_start TIMESTAMP,
  counter INT(11),
  date_end TIMESTAMP AS (ADDTIME(date_start, SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(counter/1000)))) VIRTUAL
);
```

Check it in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mTPTy9MnZ9dVuT6Pm1FHL9/0)